# Problem with .htaccess and RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have url's like games/xbox/2
2 being the page number I need the url rewritten. This is what I'm using:

```
RewriteRule games/(.*?)/$ games/consoles.php?console=$1 
RewriteRule games/(.+?)/(.+?)/$ games/consoles.php?console=$1&page=$2
```

The first rule works fine but the second is returning consoles.php as $1 instead of xbox

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule games/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ games/consoles.php?console=$1 
RewriteRule games/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ games/consoles.php?console=$1&page=$2
```

Using `(.*?)` would match even the `/` character so xbox/2 is treated as a whole

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
RewriteRule games/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ games/consoles.php?console=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule games/([^/]+)/?$ games/consoles.php?console=$1 [L]
```

I first put your most specific rule first - that way you don't do a general match, then a later more specific match mangles that general rewrite.

I also specified the `[L]` flag to signify that you want the engine to stop looking for more matches at this point.  Re-ordering the rules is redundant in this case because of the `[L]` flag, but it's a good practice to get into.

I also changed the expressions slightly.  Rather than using `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` like the previous poster said, I changed it to `([^/]+)` because that will match everything but a slash, so you can have weird console or game names.  If you want to make it more specific feel free to, but this way provides the most general use-case.