# problem with .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

I have url's like `games/xbox/2`
2 being the page number.
some url's are as follows `games/xbox-360/2`
i need the links to be rewritten.
here is the code i am using which works fine for the links with no - in them

```
RewriteRule games/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ games/consoles.php?console=$1 
RewriteRule games/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ games/consoles.php?console=$1&page=$2
```

what needs to be added to the reg expression to make it also rewrite the links that have the - in them. Thanks

Comment: this is exactly the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774211/problem-with-htaccess-and-rewriterule/3774242#3774242. Should've added it in the comments and not created a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `-` right before the `]` it will work. But a better method is to escape the `-` with a `\` so you'll end up with `[A-Za-z0-9\-]`